# What does Google App Engine provide for realtime data transfer from java app to your client?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, real-time, transfer

Are there any mechanisms for real time live data transfer-delivery like socketsa or something like that? keep-alive http connections? Are there any tutorials on this topic of realtime data transfer from  java app to your client and backwards?

Comment: As a special case, if your Java App is in fact an Android app, Android has a special API for this: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Google-I-O-day-2-The-Android-push-messaging-API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [XMPP](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

The <strike>only</strike> main type of communication Google App Engine allows is through the HTTP interface. This means that you can't initiate outbound communications from your GAE application unless your desktop application is essentially a web-server.

Keep-alive communication won't work very well either because any request lasting over 30 seconds [is automatically killed by GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Request_Timer).

The best alternative is to have your application poll your GAE app for data. This is far from ideal, but is really all that's available on GAE.

You may want a different cloud service if real-time transfers and TCP connections are required. At least until they [get it implemented in GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html).

Comment: Not true: XMPP and SMTP are also supported.

Answer (score 1):

Currently no, but they are planning to provide this at an near future release.
See http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=377 for example.

They also had demonstrated this at Google IO 2010, but not released yet.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I've starred the issue. According to the roadmap (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html) Server-push should be implemented sometime in the next 6 months.